# How to insert an array into existing multi-dimensional array by index? [Python]

Tags: python, arrays, reshape, mnist

I manipulated the MNIST dataset for research, by adding a set of digits to each digit in the dataset.

Before manipulation:

```
In:
x_train.shape

Out: 
(60000, 28, 28)
```

Expectated result after manipulation:

```
In:
x_train_new.shape

Out: 
(60000, 11, 28, 28)
```

However I messed up and forgot to add `x_train[i]` in each iteration. Therefore my shape is the following:

```
In:
x_train_new.shape

Out: 
(60000, 10, 28, 28)
```

I have tried to apply `np.insert`, however I am struggling to apply it correctly since it is a multidimensional array:

```
tryout = x_train_new[0]

In:
np.insert(tryout, 0, x_train[0])

Out:
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (28,28) into shape (28)
```

How can I insert `x_train[i]` to each ``ì```? Is it possible to insert the array as the first value in each array?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just create an empty array `x_train_expected = np.empty((60000, 11, 28, 28))` and do `x_train_expected[:,1:] = x_train_new` followed by `x_train_expected[:,0] = x_train`.

Comment: That was perfect. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an empty array

```
x_train_expected = np.empty((60000, 11, 28, 28))
```

and do

```
x_train_expected[:,1:] = x_train_new
x_train_expected[:,0] = x_train
```